# Understanding RES memory in *nix and debugging memory leaks

Tags: java, linux, memory

RE: [Possible native memory release error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523388/possible-native-memory-release-error-in-java)

It has come to my attention that `RES` memory may show much more memory than what your application has actually allotted.  In the example above, there is lots of alloc/dealloc commands but the `RES` memory gets stuck at a high number.  I know that this is not a result of JIT or other memory processes as typically you can alloc and dealloc 500M and watch the `RES` go up and down perfectly under normal circumstances.

```
jon@ubuntu-dev:~$ top -d 1 -p 31067 | grep java
 31067 jon       20   0 6847648  27988  15420 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.09 java       
 31067 jon       20   0 7769264 743952  15548 S 315.5  4.6   0:03.25 java       
 31067 jon       20   0 7900336 847868  15548 S 380.1  5.3   0:07.06 java       
 31067 jon       20   0 7834800 810324  15548 S 379.1  5.0   0:10.86 java       
 31067 jon       20   0 7703728 700028  15548 S 379.2  4.3   0:14.66 java       
 31067 jon       20   0 7900336 894940  15548 S 379.2  5.5   0:18.46 java       
 31067 jon       20   0 7703728 674400  15548 S 277.5  4.2   0:21.24 java       
 31067 jon       20   0 7376048 430868  15548 S  59.9  2.7   0:21.84 java       
 31067 jon       20   0 7376048 430868  15548 S   0.0  2.7   0:21.84 java       
 31067 jon       20   0 7376048 430868  15548 S   1.0  2.7   0:21.85 java       
 31067 jon       20   0 7376048 430868  15548 S   0.0  2.7   0:21.85 java       
 31067 jon       20   0 7376048 430868  15548 S   1.0  2.7   0:21.86 java
```

The application here is NOT holding on to that much memory.  Java says committed size is 35MB and native memory size is 0.

If this is all true, then how in the world are we supposed to be able to accurately detect memory leaks in our applications if they don't consume all the memory on the system?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the "shared" columns perhaps contains a large value? If so, your RES memory is probably due to [memory-mapped files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). This is a mechanism for efficiently accessing large data sets and it may be used internally by some library.

Comment: In that chart above shared is 15.5M

Comment: @baconoverlord Are you running with a custom `-Xmx` parameter for Java? The default maximum heap size is quite high and Java will often allocate much more memory than "is used" in order to give the Garbage Collector less work. So another possibility is just that the GC hasn't reached the maximum heap size yet, so it's keeping lots of memory which is not really needed but which might be freed if there is a need to allocate more "live" objects.

Comment: Please read the other post. Native memory is except from those limits and is deallocated directly to the OS. This issue only exists on nix.